# Getting Facebook Page Posts by Date period using Graph API

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I want to get page posts by filtering date using Facebook Graph API, but it lets me filter only one week. For example, if today is **2017-05-01**, I can get page posts between **2017-04-23** -> **2017-05-01** but I can get page posts between **2017-01-01** to **2017-04-01**. Moreover,I've tried using :

```
me?fields=feed.since(2017-01-01).until(2017-04-01)
```

and the result I've got is

`{
  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}`

Could you please show me how to get past page posts by using date period? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use unix time format for since and until parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a User Token, and grants the 'user_posts' permission.

Comment: It doesn't work! By the way, Do I need to add user_posts permission even though I need page posts?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the call to add explicitly the fields that you want to retrieve. Ex. "me/feed?fields=message,description...."